# Accessing GoogleMaps without internet connection in JSF application

Tags: google-maps, jsf, google-maps-api-3, richfaces

I have been using GoogleMaps API in my application based on JSF and RF3.3 till now for displaying google maps in the application.

For this I am using gmaps4jsf.

However as is the case for every map request, the googlemap api is requested for verification of api key.This is of no problem while my application is on public domain.

Now my application is on internal domain of my company with no internet connection to the outer world.Hence I wont be able to use gmaps4jsf or googlemaps api for the application.

What can be the possible workaround for this??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a workaround but I know an alternative: it would be to ask googlemaps api to use another tiles provider.
For example you can use OpenStreetMap tiles instead of Google Maps tiles.
[Sample here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example#Example_Using_Google_Maps_API_V3)

That shouldn't be too much work as you keep the googlemaps api.

You can freely store maps tiles from openstreetmap on your internal server.

PS: next time try [Open Layers](http://www.openlayers.org).

Comment: This gets around the issue of storing tiles (it still requires a lot of space though) but it doesn't address the licensing issue of using the API itself.

Comment: Ok you might be right. I had assumed the licensing issue was related to the map data, not the API.

Comment: Consider using OpenLayers if you need more freedom in terms of implementation. OpenLayers is Javascript based which gives you a lot of scripting flexibility. Interactivity with JSF / Richfaces 3.3.x can be done through a4j:jsFunction.

Comment: Where do I get the OpenStreetMap tiles? We need to build an application with no internet connection. Their site does not show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the free API on an intranet, so you will need a Premier/Business licence. That comes with support from Google for advice on just this sort of problem.

However: **even if you get permission to use the API on a private network** the map tiles come from the internet (unless you have the space *and* permission to store them yourself) so you are still likely to need an internet connection.